# What does the icon of a phone with “ID” written on it mean?

Tags: samsung, notification-icons, phone-app

My friend is using a Samsung Galaxy Note 10 with Android 9.0 “Pie”. This icon appears on the notification bar.

[image: a phone with “ID” written on it]

The icon also appears as the picture of some calls in the list of recent calls on the stock dialer app, mainly when the number is not saved as a contact.

Let’s say 20 calls were showing on the call list:

- 17 calls were from saved contacts. These had a circle with the initials of the contact next to the call (e.g. John Doe will be displayed as "JD").
- 1 call was what looked like a saved contact - it had a name, not just a number. It had that icon next to it.
- The last 2 are just phone numbers with that icon next to it.

What does the icon mean and when it is meant to appear?

Comment: Wild guess: it's probably has something to do with Caller ID.